# Getting all text from single XML element in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am currently trying to extract all the text from one single XML element. This usually works, but I somehow don't get it to work when there is an additional element inside. Please see my minimal example:

```py
xmlstring = """
<a>
    <b> TEXT 1 <c> PHRASE </c> TEXT 2</b>
</a>

"""

parser = etree.XMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(xmlstring, parser)
```

What I tried is:

```py
reslist = list(root.iter())
result = ' '.join([element.text for element in reslist])
```

The output is:

```
'\n\t  TEXT 1   PHRASE '
```

The desired output would be:

```
'\n\t TEXT 1   PHRASE   TEXT 2 '
```

Comment: You need to consider the `tail` property of the `c` element.

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for the duplicate question!